# $\text{AMC} \ 12A$ $2017$ $\text{Question} \ 3$

Tags: logic, contest-math

$\text{AMC 12A 2017 Question 3}$

Ms. Carroll promised that anyone who got all the multiple choice questions
right on the upcoming exam would receive an $A$ on the exam. Which of these
statements necessarily follows logically?

$(A)$ If Lewis did not receive an $A$, then he got all of the multiple choice wrong.

$(B)$ If Lewis did not receive an $A$, then he got at least one of the multiple choice
questions wrong.

$(C)$ If Lewis got at least one of the multiple choice questions wrong, then he
did not receive an $A$.

$(D)$ If Lewis received an $A$, then he got all of the multiple choice questions
right.

$(E)$ If Lewis received an $A$, then he got at least one of the multiple choice
questions right.

According to the answer key the answer is $(B)$ since the statement is: $(p)$ If you get all questions correct $\implies (q)$ You get an $A$ and $(B)$ is the contrapositive of $p \implies q$

While solving this question I considered whether it is $p \implies  q$ or $q \implies p$ since solving all questions correctly is the necessary condition for getting an $A$. So my answer was $(D)$. Can someone show me why my logic is incorrect. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving all the MCQ questions correctly is a *sufficient* condition for getting an $A$, but not a *necessary* one.

This can happen in tests with more than one component. The MCQ component carries enough weight such that if you score full marks in that part, you get an $A$ regardless of how you do in the rest of the test, so getting a full score in the MCQ component is *sufficient* for an $A$. But it may not be *necessary* because you might still be able to do well enough in the remainder of the paper that you could offset one or more incorrect MCQ responses.

You know $(B)$ is the correct option because it is given that the student did not receive an $A$ grade. He could not have got this with a full MCQ score (because that, by itself, guarantees an $A$ grade), so it is necessary that he got at least one MCQ response wrong.

Comment: The second paragraph just cleared all my doubts. Thanks!!!

Comment: Most welcome. :)